# Most efficient way to select data from one sql table and see if it matches data on another table in the same database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 2 tables, both tables have around 200,000 records.

Lets call these tables, TableA and TableB

Currently I have a function that triggers a select query, this query grabs all records in TableA that match a condition. Once I have that data, I have a foreach loop that uses the data from TableA to see if it matches any record in TableB.

The problem is that it takes a while to do this because there are so many records. I know the way Im doing it works because it does what its supposed to but it takes a good 3 minutes to finish the script. Is there a faster more efficient way to do something like this?

Thank you in advance for the help.

PS: I'm using PHP.

Comment: its called a [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: It does sound like you are doing something with PHP that should be handled by your database.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to achieve what you want is to:

**1. Create a primary key column for each table** (if you do not already have one). Example schema where column "id" is a unique identifier for the table row:

```
TableA

id    firstname   lastname
1     Michael     Douglas
2     Michael     Jackson
```

```
TableB

id   table_a_id   pet
1    1            cat
2    2            ape
3    1            dog
```

Google or search here on stackoverflow on how to [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350401/primary-key-definition-in-mysql-create-table-statement) or [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574866/add-a-primary-key-column-in-to-a-no-primay-key-old-table) a primary key for a mysql table column. An example of creating TableA with a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE `TableA` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(100),
  `lastname` varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**2. Create an SQL-query to fetch what you need**. For example:

To get all rows with at least one match in BOTH tables:

```
SELECT TableA.id, TableA.firstname, TableA.lastname, TableB.pet
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.id = TableB.table_a_id;
```

To instead get all rows from TableA, and only the matching rows from TableB:

```
SELECT TableA.id, TableA.firstname, TableA.lastname, TableB.pet
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.id=TableB.table_a_id;
```

Comment: It seems likely that he doesn't want to join on some surrogate key ... but on attributes of the underlying entities.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question ultimately depends on what you mean by **"if it matches."**

Let's assume, for a moment, that you have primary keys on each of these tables, TableA an TableB, and that you're NOT matching those.  But that you have one or more other columns, the actual data that you're storing in each row, which you are considering for your matching.  Let's call those ColA and ColB.

In that case you could use:

```
SELECT TableA.id, TableB.id, TableA.ColA, TableB.ColB 
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON (TableA.ColA = TableB.ColA)
AND (TableB.ColB = TableB.ColB);
```

... notice that we're using a complex expression on which to JOIN.  You'd want to add an `AND (TableA.XXX = TableB.XXX)` for each columned that you want to consider significant in your matching.

Of course I'm assuming that these tables don't share a common surrogate key (otherwise MicKri's JOIN would be simpler ... or a "NATURAL JOIN" would be even simpler still).

What you're doing, conceptually, is defining a pair of (mathematical) sets an finding the intersection between them.  The complication of doing this in SQL is that real world tables often have these extra columns (surrogate primary keys, and foreign keys) which aren't attributes of the underlying entities ... but which serve to map relationships among them.

In my example I'm just showing a way to formulate a JOIN query that finds the intersection based only on the attributes that are significant for your purposes.

(By the way, the parentheses in my example are there for human legibility.  They should not be required by your SQL engine ... though they don't hurt, either).

Here's one of a number of [visual explanations of SQL JOINs](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) that's handy for learning this sort of thing. An INNER JOIN is an intersection.  The ON and WHERE clauses define the subsets of the data (columns and rows, respectively) which are to be related.

Comment: Oh, by the way, it doesn't actually matter of the column names match between the tables.  If the column names in TableA were "Manufacturer" and "Style" and the corresponding names in TableB were "Maker" and "Description" ... then you'd simply change the ON conditions to TableA.Manufacturer = TableB.Maker AND ... so on.  What's important is that all of the relevant features of any entity in TableA are related to the corresponding features of the "matching" entities in TableB.